# Text field re-enter word

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Good afternoon. I would like to know if there is a method that makes the text-field capable of "remember" what the user wrote the previous times, so when the user writes the first letter a list with the proposed words will appear!! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can possible to show the list of values in tableview. you can use autocomplete.

Read this [article.](http://www.radulucaciu.ro/iphone-autocomplete-class/5/) and also with source code. This will help you.

Sample image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy, you will have to do some modifications, for example you will need to store in an `NSMutalbeArray` all the value inserted, then you will have to present a table when the user starts to edit the `UITextField` this will change as the user writes

Answer (score 0):

as your app runs, there will be many text that you need to remember/store that it will come to the point that your text that you have to remember will grow to size. you can store your text to a local database (sqlite), then as the user writes on the text field, do a search query and return the data.

unless you dont want to remember the text entered when the user used and exited/quit your app.